# Jquery slider get ui.value on handle click event

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a jquery slider covering a range of 0 to 4 and populating a read only text box with the ui.value on the slide event as is usual usage.

However sometimes the user wants to select 0 which means they wont slide at all, just click the handle. I want the text box to populate with the slider ui.value on slider handle click.

There are multiple sliders all configured the same so the text box each populates pertains to the slider used. My problem is that im grabbing the ui.value and id of the handle, what I need is the parent slider.

I can get the handle click event to operate but not grabbing the ui.value, I have tried parent() value and such derivatives.

```
$( ".slider .ui-slider-handle").on('click', function(event, ui) {
$( "#"+this.id+"Score" ).val(ui.value )
})
```

I want the value to populate the text box on handle click as well as slide.

Comment: Would it be possible to initilize the value of the ui to 0 on page load?

Comment: Unfortunately not in this instance as I need a null value where the user hasn't touched the slider, so its NULL until otherwise specified.

Comment: What is returned as event.target and event.currentTarget?

Comment: [Object HTML span element]… Hmmm I wonder is the handle a sibling rather than a child of the slider all within a span?

Comment: just checked the span holds the handle and sits inside the .slider div which carries the ui value and ID that I want

Comment: so following on form that, event.target.parentElement.id will get me the ID im after, just not sure how to grab the slider value as its not the parent element value

Comment: Assuming 0 for NULL would get me put up against a post and shot, my manager bangs on at length about the difference between 0 and NULL, very tedious in fact id rather be shot than hear that again!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! posting for others.

We get the handles slider ID from using event.target.parentElement.id and then use this to get the value:

```
$( ".slider .ui-slider-handle").on('click', function(event) {
var sliderID=event.target.parentElement.id;
$( "#"+sliderID+"Score" ).val($("#"+sliderID).slider("option", "value"));
});
```

This now populates the text box on slider handle click.